# Custom action check if IE is running then close it when it does

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, action

I'm trying to create a plugin installer for IE, so before the installation continue the IE process must be kill. But when I executed the `kill()` method on the IE process I got "Access denied" error.

What would be the best approach for this?

My Installer code:

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
    if (LaunchOnBeforeInstall())
    {
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (!process.ProcessName.StartsWith("iexplore"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("You cancelled the installation.");
    }
}

public bool LaunchOnBeforeInstall()
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("All instance of IE will be close", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    return result != DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a restricted account? Also may be worth noting that new versions of IE use threaded tab and each tab appears as a process, so you will have to kill all instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem:

```
if (!process.ProcessName.StartsWith("iexplore"))
{
process.Kill();
}
```

Your program is trying to kill everything EXCEPT for Internet Explorer